# How to hide "heads up notifications" in "immersive mode"?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an App with a VideoView that is running in the Full Screen "Immersive Mode". However, the system still pops up the "heads up notifications" when the video is running in the immersive mode. (I.e. Whatsapp notifications of new messages).

I don't want anything showing other than the video and that is the behavior I would expect from a Full Screen mode called "immersive".

Can my app hide (not show, disable, whatever) those heads up notifications?

Comment: I have the opposite problem. My notifications don't show when in immersive mode, perhaps it's to do with notification priority